# Let $u:\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ be harmonic and not surjective. Show that $u$ is bounded.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $u:\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ be harmonic and not surjective. Show that $u$  is bounded.

This question is in the context of Complex Analysis, more precisely, analytic functions. I don't know where to start. I thought about writing

$f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}(x+iy)^n$

With $v$ the conjugate harmonic of $u$. But Im getting nowhere. Any other hint from where I can start?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $u(\mathbb R ^2)$ is an interval that is not all of $\mathbb R.$